# UEFI Failure On Precision T7600

Tags: boot, system-installation

I spent the weekend working on install of Ubuntu LTS 20.04 for my Dell Precision T7600 workstation.  This workstation contains a PERC 710P controller that boots the system.  Additionally, I have an NVIDIA Quadro P5000 video card. The T7600 has zero support for secure boot. It does support UEFI though.  There is absolutely no way to disable secure boot within the BIOS, and it does not support it at all. I booted from my Ubuntu DVD that I downloaded from the official site. After my installation completed, my hardware got stuck in an infinite reboot loop. I believe the issue is related to secure boot that my hardware does not support.

I attempted the install several times with no success. The only way I was able to install successfully was to install using legacy and not UEFI. It took me a few tries to get legacy to work, because the option to delete the entire drive and install Ubuntu results in an incorrect partition that also fails to boot. The only way I successfully installed was to manually create partitions in this order:

1. 1MiB BIOS boot
2. 1GiB ext4 mounted as /boot
3. 512MiB swap
4. remainder ext4 mounted as /

After creating my partitions as above, the installation then setup Ubuntu properly that allowed for a successful boot. I have heard rumor that I lose some performance using legacy and not UEFI (I do not know how true this is, because Ubuntu still makes use of large partitions under legacy boot; I have 6TiB total disk space under RAID10)

My question is why did I encounter this infinite reboot loop?  Is this a boot bug in Ubuntu?  I face this exact same issue attempting to install the Windows 10 October cumulative update.  This was the reason I wiped my drives and switched to Ubuntu.

Any ideas on this issue?

TIA.

Comment: I think it works well to use Ubuntu with legacy boot (alias BIOS mode alias CSM). I have a Lenovo C30 workstation running that way. Ubuntu can use an MSDOS partition table or GUID partition table (GPT) independently of the boot mode. So you can use GPT and huge drives while still booting in legacy mode. (I don't think there is any performance loss.)